# iPhone: Setup static content of UITableView

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitableview

"[A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html)" from Apple, explains how to use "The Technique for Static Row Content" to use Interface Builder to setup the cells in a tableview.

I have some cells with different heights in my tableview. Without using the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method everything get messed up. Do I still need to  use this method or can I setup the height of the cells inside the IB as I created them there?

Also when using the "The Technique for Static Row Content" from the guide you still need to use the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to setup the cells even if they are created in IB. I would like to setup the full layout of the tableview with all cells in IB (drag the cells right into the tableview), is that possible in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be nice if Interface Builder could do all that, it doesn't.  To make things look correct, you have to implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  To make things easier for yourself, you could make an array and just look these things up (assuming you don't have too many rows in the table).

Comment: You don't have to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath:, unless there's some subtlety I'm missing here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. 
However, in case you have static rows only, you don't have to implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, because static cells are generated by IB.

To get cell and its content (*which is probably required to calculate height, eg, labels on different languages can have different length, resulting in a different cell size, etc*), you can use ancestor method, like that:

`UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: -1, calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` generates an infinite loop.